# Authorize attribute does not work with roles

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, identity, roles, .net-6.0

I have a controller level authorize attribute set up like this

```cs
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

And I am adding claims to my user with an overriden `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` class that is generates claims like this:

```cs
protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    var role = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            
    var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType, role.FirstOrDefault()));
            
    return identity;
}
```

But the due to the authorize attribute, my request that use it, are returning 403, even when the user has the `Administrator` role.

I have seen numerous problems like this on stackoverflow and on the web, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have checked multiple times, that I use the correct user, with the correct roles assigned.

EDIT: Added relevant parts from the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

And relevant code from Configure method from Startup.cs:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I also tried to use policy based authorization with this code and related decorators, but that did not help either:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdministratorOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role,"Administrator"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it was connected to the `context.User.Identity.RoleClaimType`. The solution that worked for me was to add configuration for JwtBearerOptions:

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions> (IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme,
    options => options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters());
```

For this to work, I also added ProfileService instead of UserClaimsPrincipalFactory. Like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<User, DatabaseContext>()
    .AddProfileService<MyProfileService>();
```

MyProfileService

```
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public MyProfileService()
    { }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        //get role claims from ClaimsPrincipal 
        var roleClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Role);

        //add your role claims 
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        // await base.IsActiveAsync(context);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end, I used both the UserClaimsPrincipalFactory and a custom ProfileService. However, it only worked with Policies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a break point to check the "role.FirstOrDefault()" value, whether it is "Administrator" or not (note the spelling).

Besides, try to use `identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"));`,

you can refer this screenshot and set the break point in your sample to check the claims:

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: @dodekja, Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem, and then share it with us via github or onedrive?

Comment: I added some code from Startup.cs

Comment: Try commenting out `services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();` and `app.UseIdentityServer();`, then whether it works well or not?

Answer (score -1):

`Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)`

Change this to

`services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)`